# Python/PIP problems

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to insall a Python library using pip and seemingkly can't get by first base.

I tried:

1. Make sure pip is installed:

python -m ensurepip --default-pip

MESSAGE: requirement already satisfied

2. Check it's up to date:

python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

MESSAGE: .... successfuly installed stup tools 40.6.2

3. Check it works:

pip --version

ERROR MESSAGE: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file

Is this a Path issue?

\lib\site packages\pip --version

MESSAGE: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please forget this - I was looking in the wrong directory - sorry

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue so many times, it's a PATH issue: if you're on windows, just go to the command line as admin and use this:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\wherever_python_is_installed_on_your_computer
```